# Issue SSL handshake with own https proxy on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, proxy, tls1.2

I try to work on my own HTTPS Proxy and I can't create my https server, during the connexion initialization, I have this error message "tlsClientError Error: 101057795:error:1407609B:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:https proxy request:openssl\ssl\s23_srvr.c:400".

Below the node JS source code:

```
private runHttpsServer() {
const instance = this;
const cert = fs.readFileSync("./certificate/server.crt", "utf8");
const key = fs.readFileSync("./certificate/key.pem", "utf8");
const options : https.ServerOptions = {
    cert: cert,
    key: key
};
const httpsServer = https.createServer(options, (req, res)=>{
    console.log("Request ...");
    instance.handleRequest.call(instance, req, res);     
});
httpsServer.on("tlsClientError", (err : Error, tlsSocket : TLSSocket)=>{
    console.log("tlsClientError", err.stack);
});
httpsServer.listen(7001);
```

}

When I browse to "https://localhost:7001/" directly without my proxy, I have no SSL handshake error. 
When I browse to other website throughout my proxy, I have this SSL Handshake error.

Someone have already encountered this issue ?
Some can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have the wrong understanding of how proxying HTTPS works. It is not that the client will make a TLS connection to the proxy as you assume but instead the client will send a plain HTTP request with the method CONNECT to the proxy in order to make the proxy establish a tunnel to the target host. Then the client will upgrade this tunnel to TLS and thus get an end-to-end protection between client and final server.

On the wire it will look something like this (the exact message might slightly vary - see [RFC 2817](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2817.txt) for details):

```
 Client ------------------------> Proxy
 - create TCP connection
 - send to proxy:
   > CONNECT google.com:443 HTTP/1.0\r\n
   > \r\n                  

                                  Proxy -----------------------------> Server
                                  - create TCP connection

 Client <------------------------ Proxy
 - send to client
   < HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established\r\n
   < \r\n

 Client <------------------------(Proxy)-----------------------------> Server
   use tunnel from client to server through proxy to
   - make the end-to-end TLS handshake
   - transfer the HTTP messages within the TLS connection
```

> ... SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:https proxy request: ...

This error message says essentially that your proxy expected the start of the TLS handshake (ClientHello) but instead got a https proxy request, i.e. `CONNECT ...`. You need to fix your proxy to properly handle https proxy requests which work as I've described.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I try to intercept the first request (the CONNECT http). I change the settings of my firefox and log all http connexion intercepted => I did'nt received anything, do you have any idea to implement with node JS ?

Comment: @KevinRamage: I have no idea what you are really doing, i.e. neither what settings you've changed in FF, what code you use now in nodejs and what problems you exactly have. But maybe you should have a look at existing projects like [this](https://github.com/joeferner/node-http-mitm-proxy) which might already do what you want.

Comment: I test several other library, I don't succeded to use it, I just test the project you mentionned, I have some SSL error but it seems work fine, thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. As mr. Steffen Ullrich answered we (me and you) have wrong understanding how proxying HTTPS work. Firstly youd need listen event CONNECTION in http then doing tls handshake. In code it look likes so:

```
http
.createServer((req, res) => requestHandler(req, res, false))
.on('connect', (req, cltSocket, head) => {
    const srvUrl = url.parse(`http://${req.url}`);
    const srvSocket = net.connect(
        srvUrl.port,
        srvUrl.hostname,
        () => {
            cltSocket.write('HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established\r\n'
                + 'Proxy-agent: Node.js-Proxy\r\n'
                + '\r\n');
            srvSocket.write(head);
            srvSocket.pipe(cltSocket).on('error', (e) => console.log('srvSocket', e));
            cltSocket.pipe(srvSocket).on('error', (e) => console.log('cltSocket', e));
        },
    );
})
.listen(9000, () => console.log('HTTP Server started listening on port 9000'));
```

you can learn about it in official site of [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_connect)

Full code of my https proxy is available [here.](https://github.com/bin-umar/http-proxy/blob/master/app.js#L121)